# Defining a function in terms of interpolating functions

Tags: interpolation

I had a question regarding multiplying an interpolation function with a regular function such as

Let f and g be two interpolation functions in the domain defined by $0 \le x \le 1$ and $0 \le y \le 1$

then how do you compute 
$(1+x^2) \frac{df}{dx} + \frac{dg}{dx}$ ?

I tried

```
h = Evaluate[D[f, {x, 1}]](1 + x^2) + Evaluate[D[g, {x, 1}]]
```

but it doesn't work because we can't sum two interpolation functions.

Therefore, I tried

```
h = 
  FunctionInterpolation[
    Evaluate[D[f, {x, 1}]](1 + x^2) + Evaluate[D[g, {x, 1}]], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

This works, however I wanted to check the accuracy of the derivative just to make sure everything is correct, so I computed

```
temp1 = FunctionInterpolation[Evaluate[D[f, {x, 1}]], {x, 0, 1},{y, 0, 1}]
temp2 = Evaluate[D[f, {x, 1}]]
```

and evaluate it at `x = 0.5` and `y = 0.5`. The results of `temp1` and `temp2` have deviations. Is there a better way to do this. I would appreciate any advice I can get.

Comment: Does `f'[x] (1 + x^2) + g'[x]` work?

Comment: Where are `f` and `g` coming from?

Comment: f and g solutions from a finite element problem over a finite element mesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems straightforward to me. Note that I do the interpolation on data points of the form `{x, f[x]}` to get the domain right, and that I do not explicitly call `Evaluate` in this code.

```
f = Interpolation[Table[{x, Sin[2 π x]}, {x, 0, 1, .01}]];
g = Interpolation[Table[{x, Cos[2 π x]}, {x, 0, 1, .01}]];

h[x_] = (1 + x^2) f'[x] + g'[x];
```

Now let's plot `h` against its exact form

```
hx[x_] = (1 + x^2) D[Sin[2 π x], x] + D[Cos[2 π x], x]
```

The combined plot shows that `h` and `hx` conform as well as can be expected.

```
Plot[{h[x], hx[x]}, {x, 0, 1}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Directive[AbsoluteThickness[7]], AbsoluteThickness[1.5]},
  PlotLegends -> {h, hx}]
```

[image: plot]